# d3.js area chart - json data not binding to chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm stumped trying to get this json data to render. Thank you for the suggestions below I made some progress trying your solutions but not quite there yet.

Thank you.

```
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/9dv55t4q/

d3.json("http://www.corsproxy.com/dvl.thomascooper.com/data/kruggerrand.json",
function(error, data) { ...fiddle data...}
```

Comment: I think you've got a number of problems. First, you should take a look at your `d3.json` call and compare it with the documentation. Second, take a look at the JSON that get's returned. `data.data` has your dates and values and it's an array of arrays. Try `console.log(data)` once you get your d3.json call working. Maybe that'll get you started?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `type` is undefined. It's also not necessary.

You might also want to think twice about posting your auth_token on a public web site like stackoverflow or jsfiddle.